# Spring @Autowired injection doesn't work : DAO is always null

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired, struts-1

I am working on an EAR with actions handled by Struts and beans by Spring. This EAR includes 3 `.jar` files, the references of the commons files (DS/US/DAO), and a `.war`, **myProjectWeb**.

**Code :**

The Struts action (in *myProjectWeb*) :

```
public class MyAction extends DispatchAction {

    private IMyPreferencesDS myPreferences;

    protected ActionForward executeAction(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, 
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        // newValue is got from my form
        myPreferences.updatePreferences(newValue);
    }
}
```

The different DSs (in *myProject-commons*) :

**`IMyPreferencesDS`** :

```
public interface IMyPreferencesDS extends IAbstractDSGeneric<MyDTO> {

    void updatePreferences(String newValue) throws JrafDomainException;

}
```

**`MyPreferencesDS`** :

```
public class MyPreferencesDS implements IMyPreferencesDS {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="myPersistenceUnit")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myPreferencesDAOBean")
    private IMyPreferencesDAO mainDao;

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = JrafDomainRollbackException.class, 
        noRollbackFor = JrafDomainNoRollbackException.class)
    public void updatePreferences(String newValue) throws JrafDomainException {

        mainDao.setNewPreferencesValue(newValue);

    }
}
```

**`IMyPreferencesDAO`** :

```
public interface IMyPreferencesDAO extends IAbstractDAOGeneric<MyEntity> {

    void setNewPreferencesValue(String newValue) throws JrafDaoException;

}
```

**`MyPreferencesDAO`** :

```
public class MyPreferencesDAO extends AbstractDAOGenericImpl<MyEntity> implements IMyPreferencesDAO {

    public void setNewPreferencesValue(String newValue) throws JrafDaoException {
        StringBuilder strQuery = new StringBuilder();
        strQuery.append("update MYBASE.MYTABLE ");
        strQuery.append("set");
        strQuery.append(" PREFS=:newValue, ");

        final Query myQuery = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(strQuery.toString(), MyEntity.class);
        myQuery.setParameter("newValue", newValue);

        try {
            return myQuery.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Config :**

In *myProjectWeb* :

**`struts-config`** :

```
<form-bean name="MyForm" type="com.my.MyForm"/>
<action input="/media/modificationPopup.jsp" name="MyForm" path="/media/prefModif" 
    scope="request" type="org.springframework.web.struts.DelegatingActionProxy" 
    validate="true"/>
```

**`actions-dependencies`** :

```
<bean name="/media/prefModif" class="com.my.action.MyAction" scope="singleton">
    <property name="myPreferences" ref="myPreferencesDS" />
</bean>
```

**`application-context-spring`** :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd">

    <!-- Enterprise layer's dependencies -->
    <import resource="classpath:ioc/0-ref-commons-enterpriselayer-dependencies.xml" />

    <bean id="springLocator" class="com.afklm.jraf.bootstrap.locator.SpringLocator"></bean>

    <bean id="persistenceUnitManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence-web.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myEmf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPersistenceUnit" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.my.action" /> 
</beans>
```

**`0-ref-commons-enterpriselayer-dependencies.xml`** is contained into the *commons* jar :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">
    <import resource="1-ref-commons-ds-dependencies.xml"/>
    <import resource="2-ref-commons-us-dependencies.xml"/>
    <import resource="3-ref-commons-daos-dependencies.xml"/>
</beans>
```

It contains the requested DS and DAO, like this :

In **`1-ref-commons-ds-dependencies.xml`**

```
<!-- MyPreferencesDS Component -->
<bean id="myPreferencesDS" class="com.commons.ds.MyPreferencesDS" scope="prototype">
</bean>
```

In **`3-ref-commons-daos-dependencies.xml`**

```
<!-- MyPreferencesDAO Component -->
<bean id="myPreferencesDAOBean" class="com.commons.daos.MyPreferencesDAO" scope="prototype">
</bean>
```

All the libs are in my EAR :

[image]

And imported into my Web .war :

[image]

My **EAR**'s module assembling :

[image]

Ok here it is... But when I try to call this line in **MyPreferencesDS** :

```
mainDao.setNewPreferencesValue(newValue);
```

**mainDao** is always null and I get a `NullPointerException`... Seems like the `@Autowired` injection doesn't work there.

Thanks for your help...

Comment: i dont see on your code , But when i had the same problems. the reasons were 1) Spring dont see the needed class (add @Component or other annotation)

Comment: 2) tried to get data from new Class() where i had injected method;

Answer (score 1):

Ypu have a mixture of @Autowiring and direct assigning via xml.

Your myAction doesn't have autowired preferences. You set it via ref

```
<bean name="/media/prefModif" class="com.my.action.MyAction" scope="singleton">
    <property name="myPreferences" ref="myPreferencesDS" />
</bean>
```

So define the dao ref the same way by ref.

```
<bean id="myPreferencesDS" class="com.commons.ds.MyPreferencesDS" scope="prototype">
    <property name="mainDao" ref="myPreferencesDAOBean" />
</bean>
```

Or use @Autowire to inject preferences into the Action

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I tried it with putting `@Autowired` in the Struts action too (and removing the property def in `actions-dependencies`) but I'm still having the problem.

Comment: Try to add @ Service or @ Component annotation to the DAO and Preferences classes

Answer (score 0):

You are not scanning "`com.commons`" package. Since "`com.commons.ds.MyPreferencesDS`" is in that package, spring will not even it needs to autowire beans of this package. you may want to try the below line in `application-context-spring`:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.my.action, com.commons" />
```

if you dont want all the packages under "`com.commons`" and be more specific about what packages that are scanned and list all of them:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.my.action, com.commons.ds, com.commons.daos" />
```

Comment: Yeah I tried to add the ds, dao and action packages in component scaning but it still won't work... my intuition is that there is a problem in the link between the `web` and the `commons` parts of the project... (the action is in `web` while the DS and the DAO are in `commons`).

Comment: you may be right. is it possible to share your web.xml? I am interested to see your contextConfigLocation

Comment: can you change import declarations like this - <import resource="classpath*:ioc/0-ref-commons-enterpriselayer-dependencies.xml" /> and check